# Entity Framework 5 and Code First - Can I get it to do a Rename instead of Drop and Create?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF 5 Code First. I have the following Fluent API code that sets a navigation property for 'SaleZipCode'.

```
private void MyTable(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyType>()
        .HasRequired(a => a.SaleZipCode)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(map => map.MapKey("SaleZipCodeId"));
}
```

I realize I misnamed 'SaleZipCode' and it should be 'ZipCode'. However, when I do this, EF attempts to drop the SaleZipCode column and add a ZipCode column when I do an Update-Database, instead of just doing a rename. This doesn't work because I have existing data in the table. Is there a way I can get EF to do a rename and not a drop and recreate?

Answer (score 0):

Renaming property in your entity should not affect database, because there is no `SaleZipCode` column in database. Foreign key is mapped to `SaleZipCodeId` column, and only changing this foreign key column mapping will affect database. E.g. if you will change mapping to

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyType>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.Foo) // changing this will not affect database
    .WithMany()
    .Map(map => map.MapKey("ZipCodeId")); // column name changed
```

Then following migration will be generated

```
public override void Up()
{
    RenameColumn(table: "dbo.MyTypes", 
                 name: "SaleZipCodeId", newName: "ZipCodeId");
}

public override void Down()
{
    RenameColumn(table: "dbo.MyTypes", 
                 name: "ZipCodeId", newName: "SaleZipCodeId");
}
```

Simple renaming columns, data will be preserved.

Comment: Maybe in theory this is what EF is supposed to do. But, in fact, what EF is trying to do is to add a new column:  ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[MyTable] ADD [ZipCodeId] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

Comment: @RandyMinder that is in fact. Code is verified on real database with data